# Pandas: compare two columns and find cells that are both not empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with 5 columns but I am interested only in columns A, B and C.

A and B contain multiple names, C is an empty column.
I want to fill C column with the value of B if and only if A and B are **both** not empty (`!=""`).

The desired output would be something like this :

[image: example output]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I used NumPy's [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```py
import numpy as np

df['C'] = np.where((df['A'] != '') & (df['B'] != ''), df['B'], '')
```

Comment: `df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] != '', df['B'], '')` is better @gustavoql @Artemis

Comment: @ansev I agree! I hadn't thought of it that way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a single liner

```
df.C = df.B if df.A.any() else ''
```

> You can modify df.A.any() to any condition you want such as `not df.A.empty()`

but this solves your issue.

Comment: This seems to copy the values even if only one of the condition is met